# Styling link using a:active state after 301 redirect

Tags: css, redirect, hyperlink

I want to style the `a:active` state links in my navigation menu using `<CSS>`. The problem is that I have added one link which has a 301 permanent redirect attached to it. When this link is clicked, the page will automatically redirect to another URL.

> I am using Magento and the link that I wanted to appear in the menu bar
>   is for a CMS page (not one of the categories). This question basically
>   has nothing to do with Magento, but if you want to know more about why
>   and how I did this you can learn more [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/adding-page-links-in-the-navigation-bar).

So my question is: How can I style this link using the `a:active` state, when it is being 301 redirected  permanently to another URL? Is this possible at all?

Comment: Nope...CSS styles content. It has no way of detecting whether the hyperlink is valid or not.

Comment: What you **can** do is target hyperlinks with a specific URL (or component of a URL)...would that help?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by targeting. How does it work?

Comment: See this link and scroll down to  nos. 11, 12, 13 & 14. They may help [**30 CSS Selectors You Should Memorize**](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048)

Comment: The page you refer to looks helpful. I'll look into it and see if I can get this to work. Thank you @Paulie_D!